# I don't eat meat since then vs haven't eaten

Tags: present-perfect, present-simple

I've stumbled on this " I don't eat meat since then".

And this seems like a meaning that should be expressed with a present perfect construction:
"I haven't eaten meat since then".

Is there some support for using present simple in such a context typically assigned to present perfect?

Comment: Present Simple is syntactically fine here. It's just that *idiomatically*, most native speakers usually use Present *Perfect* in such contexts. But it's a stylistic choice, not a grammatical rule.

Comment: Compare 1: *I haven't seen him since he hit me* and 2: *I don't go out with him since he hit me* (ignore the fact that ***since*** in #2 could in principle mean ***because***; assume it has the same meaning as in #1).

Comment: Stumbled where? Who wrote it? A native or non-native speaker? Was it only a comment or part of a longer text? -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, English generally prefers the present perfect in this kind of situation:

> I haven't eaten meat since then.

This tells us about what has happened until the present time but doesn't tell us anything about what will happen in five minutes. Perhaps the speaker is holding a hamburger and will eat it? In order to suggest that the action is ongoing, the speaker might use the simple present tense instead<sup>1</sup>:

> I don't eat meat since then.

This is fairly common in such situations. Here is an example from a recent translation of a letter from Dostoevsky:

> So that since yesterday I no longer eat and only drink tea.<sup>2</sup>

This suggests that his lack of food and drinking of tea are ongoing.

---

<sup>1</sup> [The British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/present-simple) says that this use of the simple present describes "something that happens regularly in the present".

<sup>2</sup> Joseph Frank, [*Dostoevsky: The Miraculous Years, 1865-1871*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dostoevsky/zf_RDwAAQBAJ), Princeton University Press, 2020, pg. 35.

Comment: There are no examples cited using present simple and "since". It's +1 if you can find a reputable source that says PS with "since" is acceptable. It probably is but I believe the speaker, without realising, made a mistake.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I've added a recent example from a very reputable writer & publisher but wasn't sure whether you thought that a reference to an actual grammar authority was needed, too. If you think so, I can try to find one.